# Cannot load page to scrape the article tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screen-scraping, article

I am trying to scrape the content of the article on this link: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/jvim.15224

I have used Selenium to load the page (both PhantomJS and Firefox), but I cant seem to get the article tag.

This line was to wait for the page to load:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "article-section__sub-title section1")))
```

Alternatively, I also tried to wait for the article tag to load.

However, the driver continues after a couple of secs, but whenever I check the html I got after waiting, the only thing that comes out is the 'head' and 'body' tags - just tags, without their content.

Any idea what I did wrong with getting the page to load and scrape the article tag?

Comment: Try with headless chrome, phantomjs is been outdated now and headless chrome is way faster

Comment: Which element are you referring by _article_ tag?

Answer (score 1):

To scrape the article tags instead of using `presence_of_element_located()` you need to use **`visibility_of_all_elements_located()`** method and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/jvim.15224")
  tags = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.article-section__sub-title.section1")))
  for tag in tags:
      print(tag.text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Background
  Objective
  Animals
  Methods
  Results
  Conclusions and Clinical Importance
  ```